# Fetch the arguments inside a parenthesis and add it to a list in Java

Tags: java, regex

input:

```
(cl(A, B, 0.620) :-  /* #pos=1,513 *
```

Expected Output:

```
Fetch and Add A and B to a list
```

Code (Attempt 1):

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(inputString);
            while(m2.find()) 
                {
                System.out.println(m2.group(1));
                }
```

Output:

```
cl(A, B, 0.620
```

Code Attempt 2:

```
System.out.println(inputString.substring(inputString.indexOf("(")+1,inputString.indexOf(")")));
```

Still getting the same output.

Please suggest me on what is the mistake.

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: You are matching from the first open parentheses you encounter to the first closed parentheses - what you (seem to) want requires actual parsing of the string to match opening and closing parentheses

Comment: @MaulikDoshi Use case is to fetch the arguments inside the paranthesis.

Comment: What is your expected output?  You never told us this.  By the way, if you expressions get any more complex than this, e.g. with nested parentheses, then you might want to consider writing a parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fetch the arguments inside the paranthesis and add them to a ArrayList. But the part I am struck is to fetch the arguments.

Comment: You could use `"\\(([^()]*)\\)"` to match a string from `(` to `)` with no parentheses in between, and split `group(1)` value the way Tim showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your current attempt is that your pattern is wrong:

```
\\((.*?)\\)
```

This matches a *single* opening parenthesis, followed by a *single* closing parenthesis.  Note that the capture group in the pattern doesn't count; those parentheses won't be matched.  Instead, use the following pattern:

```
\\(.*?\\((.*?)\\)
```

**Full code:**

```
String inputString = "(cl(A, B, 0.620) :-  /* #pos=1,513 *";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(inputString);
if (m2.find()) {
    String match = m2.group(1);
    String[] parts = match.split(",\\s+");
    for (String part : parts) {
        list.add(part);
        System.out.println("Found an item: " + part);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found an item: A
Found an item: B
Found an item: 0.620
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester